# How to prove that the subsequential limits are the same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given two sequences: {$a_n$}$_{n=0}^{\infty}$  and {$b_n$}$_{n=0}^{\infty}$

Prove that: if $ \lim_{n\to\infty}$ $ (a_n-b_n ) = 0$  then all the subsequential limits of both sequences are the same

I tried to prove it by proving that each option of subsequence limit of these both sequences are equal, tried to take two subseqenece limits k and l for both of them and proved that they are the same, but I have a problem with that if the subsequence limit is infinity then i didn't know what to do...
Any ideas of how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s very similar to the way you deal with finite limits.

Let $\langle a_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a subsequence of $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle b_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ the corresponding subsequence of $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and suppose that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=\infty$. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ there is a $k_x\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_{n_k}>x$ whenever $k\ge k_x$, and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0$, there is an $\ell\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_{n_k}-b_{n_k}|<1$ whenever $k\ge\ell$. Now let $x\in\Bbb R$, and suppose that $k\ge\max\{\ell,k_{x+1}\}$; then $a_{n_k}>x+1$, and $|a_{n_k}-b_{n_k}|<1$, so $b_{n_k}>x$. Thus, $\lim_{k\to\infty}b_{n_k}=\infty$, as desired.